# Proof that integral of uniformly convergent series converges to sum of the integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

I'm confused about the proof of a simple corollary.

We're given that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly then $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.
$$

As a corollary, my textbook considers the case that if

- the sums $\sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)$ converge uniformly
- the $g_k$ are Riemann integral on $[a,b]$

then $$
\int_a^b \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k(x)\right)\,dx =
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\int_a^b g_k(x)\,dx\right).
$$

The proof defines $f_n(x) \triangleq \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)$ and states that the conclusion follows from the given since $$
\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx \to \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.
$$

This proof seems incomplete to me, however. How do we know that $$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\int_a^b g_k(x)\,dx\right) \text{ ?}
$$

Comment: For finite sums you have $\int \sum_k = \sum_k \int$. So, if $s_n$ is the finite sum and $s$ the sum, you have $\int s_n \to \int s$.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what part of the proof you think is incomplete?

Comment: $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)$.  Take $S_n(x)$ as a uniformly convergent sequence.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: write the result of the corollary exactly the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k(x)\right)dx &=
\int_a^b f(x)dx \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)dx\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \left(\sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)\right)dx\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\int_a^b g_k(x)dx\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\int_a^b g_k(x)dx\right)
\end{align*}
$$

--- rk

Comment: Thanks. The part I was missing was that for finite sums we can swap the order of the summation and the integral. And then taking the limit does it.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$, we have $$\int_a^b f_n(x)dx=\int_a^b \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_a^b g_k(x)dx.$$  Now we take the limit as $n\to\infty$.  The limit of the left side of this equation is $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ and the limit of the right side is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^b g_k(x)dx$, so those two must be equal.